# Joomla MVC Component - Custom save function for a single record

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, custom-component

I've created a custom Joomla MVC component which keeps track of car mileage information. An important part of this is to archive old mileage information on a per car basis and able to display this to a logged in user. What I'm trying to do is to "archive" old mileage information to a separate table in my database when the mileage is being updated. Now I don't know exactly how to override the default save() function but I wanted to start with a custom Toolbar function that is able to write the record to a table. Plain and simple. This is what I did so far:

I've added a new button my toolbar in administrator/components/com_cars/views/car/view.html.php

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('car.archive', 'archive.png', 'archive_f2.png', 'Archive Mileage', false);
```

Then I added the function archive to "administrator/components/com_cars/controllers/car"

Adding a simple echo statement confirms that the button is working. However, the next thing I need is that the information of the active record (i.e. the record that was opened from the list) is written to the new table when the "Archive Mileage" button is clicked. So basically I'm doing a duplication of the record that is selected but saving it to a different table. I therefore need to alter the programming so a different table is used to put the data in. This is how my controller file for "car" (not cars) is looking right now:

```
 class CarsControllerCar extends JControllerForm
 {
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->view_list = 'cars';
    parent::__construct();
}
public function archive()
{

    // Get the input
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $ids    = $this->input->get('cid', array(), 'array');

    try
    {
        if (empty($ids))
        {
            throw new Exception(JText::_('COM_CARS_NO_ELEMENT_SELECTED'));
        }

        ArrayHelper::toInteger($ids);
        $model = $this->getModel();
        $model->archive($ids);
        $this->setMessage(Jtext::_('COM_CARS_ITEMS_SUCCESS_DUPLICATED'));
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($e->getMessage(), 'warning');
    }

    $this->setRedirect('index.php?option=com_cars&view=cars');

}

}
```

This should then pass the data to the model which inserts it into the right table. How I should construct the model in the best possible way to receive and process the data is not entirely clear anymore. Can I simply use a database query to add it to the database or should I use code according to the duplicate function to get the job done?

It is a bit fuzzy for me how to get the data of this particular record into the controller and then pass it to the model for processing it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('car.archive', 'archive.png', 'archive_f2.png', 'Archive Mileage', false);
```

To

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('car.archive', 'archive.png', 'archive_f2.png', 'Archive Mileage', true);
```

The last paremeter let you choose elements from list, and then in your controller you should be able to get id of elements from

```
$ids    = $this->input->get('cid', array(), 'array');
```

**Edit**

To get id of item from button click inside item page, just get id param from input :

```
$this->input->get('id', null, 'int');
```

**Explanations**

All toolbar button work in the same way, clicking on it will put the acton in "action" field of joomla form and the post it, so when you show an item page it's ever from a post action.

Comment: I understand what your saying but I won't have to select a value from the list as I'm in the edit form of the item. So I'm not doing anything on the record list overview, I've already made the selection.

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work. In my console I can see that the application expects a selected item. Since I'm on the item page itself this is shouldn't be an issue and the current record should be taken. Using "false" in my action statement skips the error but redirects to where the controller is pointing and display an error message that no record was selected. I'll edit my question a bit into more detail so you know what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: See the edit I've made, use $this->input->get('id', null, 'int');